# Configure value manually and change color of box(circle) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is simple javascript code which has 3 function Increment(), Stop(), Start().

```
var value = 0;
var end;

function Increment(){
    value++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Value: ' + value + '<br />';    
}
end = setInterval(Increment, 1000);

function Stop(){
    clearInterval(end); 
}

function Start(){
    end = setInterval(Increment, 1000); 
}


<p id="counter"></p></br>
<div>
    <input id= "btn1" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="Stop()">
    <input id = "btn2" type="button" value="Start Again" onclick="Start()">             
</div>
```

1. How can I manually configure the value; like I would enter a desired value and it will start from that value.
2. How can I set a threshold value, after crossing the threshold value, the corresponding box/circle will change the color.

Thanks, Kind Regard,

Comment: Do you know what an `if` statement is? I would start there.

Comment: @epascarello Yes I know `if` statement. Can you tell me the idea to proceed?

Comment: So you compare the number to what you want to be the max. Change what you want inside the if. Grab the start number from a textbox or where ever you want to get the value from.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you mean how could you on the code side set the value, then you would simply change the var value = 0 line to whatever value you want.  If you want the user to be able to set the value, then you would use an input to get the user value and then set that as the var value =.
2. In your script, add a line in Increment() like "if (value >= *_*) {" with your threshold value in the blank, and then add your color-change code after the bracket.

Comment: I m asking from the user side.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an input field that allows the user to set an initial value. I also don't recommend writing inline JavaScript - take a look into the subject of unobtrusive JavaScript.

Here's how your `startCounting()` should look like:

```
// Hold our counter info
var counter = {
    currValue: 0,
    interval: null
};

function startCounting() {
    // Set the current value if provided
    counter.currValue = startValueField.value || 0;
    counter.interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);
}
```

I'll leave adding the threshold value as an exercise. It's the same idea.

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6QjjD/3/)</kbd>